# Create custom registration form html

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to create a website, where I should be able to create events (based on dates) for employee (through admin login) and employees should be able to view the events and nominate them self for the events. The events should be only created through admin page. Also I want to create event categories, which should be only shown under the same category selected which creating the event. 
Any idea where I can learn how to create this as I am new to HTML.

I have created a login page so far and the multiple nomination category pages.

Comment: Basic grammar edits

Answer (score -1):

According to your question and your described project I assume that this will be a tough challenge for you to realize at this level of knowledge/skills.

You will need some kind of database to store your data and grab it as needed.

Therefor you should dive into php/SQL stuff:

https://www.php.net/ 
https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQL_Tutorial

Also you should learn basic javascript libraries that will ease up things, like:

https://jquery.com/ etc.

As for HTML/CSS there are plenty of resources on the web. I suggest to learn the basics and how they interact when it comes to web development and then research further as your debugging problems increase ;-).

Good luck.